# Point of junction. How to remove seam

Tags: modeling, mesh, mirror-modifier, curve-modifier, seams

I have an issue when modeling ring with Mirror and Curve modifier. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Those are probably the un-merged end vertices. You can use the *Weld modifier* to merge them.

Comment: Working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By using the weld modifier, you can merge the vertices, thus hiding the seam.